# jQuery - Create a Tip box / Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-widgets

On my webApp, I need to create a tip functionality, which is a div with a close button, managed by browser cookie. If user closes one, it closes on all the page.

I couldn't find a jQuery plugin for this functionality, so thought of creating one of my own. Tried using jQuery dialog widget, but haven't been able to make it run on the same page. It always runs as a modal.

What are my options? How do I solve this problem?

Comment: if talking about a mix of Tip box and Dialog, maybe intro.js https://github.com/usablica/intro.js could fit your needs? it also can remember that user closed it and wont appear again

Comment: Tried using intro.js, but doesnt seem to be working at all.  Imported, as `code` <script type="text/javascript"  src="/plugins/introjs/intro.min.js" /></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/plugins/introjs/introjs.min.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/plugins/introjs/introjs-rtl.min.css" /> 
<!-- Add Nazanin template -->
<link href="/plugins/introjs/themes/introjs-nazanin.css" rel="stylesheet">
`code`

Comment: & added a dialog as - `code`       <div  id="dialog">
        test tip text
                    </div>  `code`  and under javascript block- introJs("#dialog").start();

Comment: Can you try using http://www.jsfiddle.com or summular to show your code and results than ppl could help you better